# Filter nsmutable array by CGRectIntersectsRect

Tags: ios, iphone, performance, cgrectintersectsrect

I wanna extract from an array of SKSpriteNode only the elements that intersect with a predeterminated frame. I can do it by a for iteration:

```
 for (SKSpriteNode* Object in Array) {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Frame,Object.frame)) {
         //extraction code
    }
 }
```

However performace of this method seems to be poor,there's a way to do this operation in a faster way? I have tried something like this:

```
NSPredicate *Predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"CGRectIntersectsRect(Frame,SELF.frame)"];
   NSArray *Results = [Array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:Predicate];
```

But this create the error "Unable to parse function name 'CGRectIntersectsRect' into supported selector (CGRectIntersectsRect)". What's wrong? Using a predicate instead a for will give me some gain in performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since predicate parser cannot recognize a free-standing C function, you can make a predicate from a block:

```
NSPredicate *intersects = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id obj, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return CGRectIntersectsRect(Frame, obj.frame);
}];
NSArray *results = [Array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:intersects];
```

I am not sure about the performance gain in comparison to the loop, though, because the number of comparisons is going to remain unchanged.